# breakers all putting out power but outlet not working

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker, gfci

Was using a power drill on a gfci outlet and power suddenly stopped.  The trip light did not go on on the outlet but the test button cannot be pushed (means no power, correct?) I took off the gfci and tested the incoming wires - no power.  I've checked every room in the house for a tripped gfci but there aren't any.  I went to breaker panel and no breakers were tripped.   I tested each breaker and they are all outputting 120 volts.  The breakers are very poorly labeled and I can't tell which one goes to the gfci. Is there a way to pinpoint which breaker runs to the gfci?  Can there even be a problem with the breaker if it is outputting 120 volts?

Comment: Most likely there are multiple GFCI’s on the circuit, improperly daisy chained.   They need to be reset in order away from the panel (because a GFCI won’t reset unless it’s has power).   This is a very common occurrence.   Go on a GFCI hunt and I bet you will find another upstream that is tripped.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any other receptacles or lights with no power? Presumably there are other receptacles on this same circuit.

You say no power at the incoming line to this receptacle--presumably meaning no hot. So a connection of a hot upstream has gone bad. Do you have spring "backstab" connections to the receptacles? If so, change them to the side screw. (If you have *backwire* connections secured by the screw that is fine.)

In any case, check each receptacle in the circuit from the non-working one going back towards the panel. Use a plug-in circuit tester or a multimeter. It will tell whether there is no hot or no neural at each receptacle.